# Visual C++ 2010 - Fastest method to convert a 10 GB BYTE array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, byte, stdstring

**Question:** What is the fastest method to convert a 10 GB BYTE array to a standard string with hex format in Visual C++?

**What I am doing:** I am using std::fread(...) to read a very large file into a large buffer and then formatting it to hex format and then converting it to std::string. I hope I make sense.

I am currently using this piece of code (not written by me...) which is slow.

```
std::string ByteToHexFormatStdStr( __in ::BYTE *ByteArray, __in int ArraySize, __in bool AddSpace )
{
    ::BYTE Byte = NULL;
    const char HexCharacters[ 16 ] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
    std::string Return = "";

    for( ::UINT Index = 0; Index < ArraySize; ++ Index )
    {
        Byte = ( ::BYTE )( ByteArray[ Index ] & 0xF0 );
        Byte = ( ::BYTE )( Byte >> 4 );
        Byte = ( ::BYTE )( Byte & 0x0F );
        Return += HexCharacters[ ( int )Byte ];
        Byte = ( ::BYTE )( ByteArray[ Index ] & 0x0F );
        Return += HexCharacters[ ( int )Byte ];

        if( AddSpace ) Return += ' ';
    }

    return ( Return );
}
```

Comment: Adding one character at a time to the destination string like that is likely to be pretty slow -- probably better to pre-allocate space in your destination string (`string::reserve`, assuming you're using C++11). Unless you have 10s of gigabytes of RAM available, anything you do like this is going to be really slow -- probably better to process file to file instead of string to string.

Comment: I don't remember for sure, but VC++ 2010 *may* have `std::string::reserve`. If not, you might want to use  `vector<char>` instead. Still not clear why you need/want to do this (with destination in memory) at all though.

Comment: I vote for Jerry Coffin's comment, mainly the last part: ".. [likely] better to process file to file .."

Comment: @JerryCoffin it does. But unless this is running on a 64bit machine in 64bit native-code, forget about this working *at all*. the 4GB virtual address space will easily stop this from getting very far.

Comment: @WhozCraig: True, but sine he's only complaining about speed, rather than its not working at all, I assumed he must be running 64-bit code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is unlikely to be in the routine that converts the data to hexadecimal.

The problem is almost certainly that you're just using *way* too much memory. Each byte of input becomes two bytes of hexadecimal. If you add spaces between them, that makes three bytes of output for each one of input.

If you're starting with 10 gigabytes of input, that means you're producing 20 or 30 gigabytes of output. Since you're expanding your destination string incrementally, chances are good that it's going to resize its buffer and copy the data several times before it gets to the full 30 gigabytes. During a resize/copy operation, it needs memory space for the old copy *and* the new one, simultaneously. Depending on what factor it uses when it resizes, changes are good that you're using (or trying to use) somewhere around 60 gigabytes of RAM. Unless you actually have at least 64 gigabytes of physical RAM, that's almost certainly going to be *quite* slow.

Chances are pretty good that you'd be better off doing the processing by reading from one file and writing to another. In fairness, this still isn't going to be extremely fast unless you have *really* fast hard drives -- and by strong preference you read from one and write to another.

Unless you do have that 64Gig of physical RAM, processing from file to file will still almost certainly be faster than using virtual memory though.

```
std::string ToHex(char input)
{
    const char Hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    std::string Return;

    Return += Hex[(unsigned)input>>4 & 0xf];
    Return += Hex[(unsigned)input & 0xf];
    return Return;
}

std::transform(std::istream_iterator<char>(infile),
               std::istream_iterator<char>(),
               std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(outfile, ""),
               ToHex);
```

For the equivalent of your AddSpace being true, change the second parameter to the `ostream_iterator` from `""` to `" "`.

For this large of files, you might want to do your own file handling though -- since you're apparently running on Windows, for this size of file, you can probably gain quite a bit by using `CreateFile` directly, and specifying [`FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950.aspx) to avoid thrashing the cache as you do this. Read in chunks of, say, 4 megabytes or so, transform to another, and write out the result. If you have two (or more) discs so you can read from one as you write to the other, you could also consider using overlapped I/O to allow reading from one file, writing to the other, and processing to happen simultaneously. If you're only using one disc, that would still allow processing and I/O to happen in parallel, but the processing will be enough faster than the I/O that it probably won't gain enough to justify the effort.

Comment: If you're advising FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFFERING the alignment restrictions on the read-buffer should probably be mentioned as well. Just specifying the flag won't cut it (and in fact, the read will fail outright) unless the buffer is aligned on a clean multiple of the sector size of the volume holding the file.

Comment: @WhozCraig: true -- I assume he'll look it up and follow the requirements (but I'll add a link to MSDN to help out).

Comment: Alright, thanks Jerry Coffin. I will try this: process file to file.

Answer (score 0):

I guarantee this will be within epsilon of the fastest possible implementation:

```
#define _CRT_DISABLE_PERFCRIT_LOCKS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    _setmode(fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
    _setmode(fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);

    char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(hex[c >> 4]);
        putchar(hex[c & 0xF]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run as `thisprog < in > out`.

On MSVC++, stdio operations use locking to allow threadsafe behaviour in multithreading code.  We don't need that for this single-threaded program, so we turn it off with the top line (described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235356.aspx)), which can speed things up a lot.  The calls to `_setmode()` turn on binary mode for the standard input and output streams, which are in text mode (`\r\n` translated into `\n` on input and vice versa) by default.

It's fast because stdio uses its own internal buffering, so you're not asking the OS for one character at a time (the OS additionally does its own disk buffering in the background).

If you're determined to use C++, change `#include <stdio.h>` to `#include <cstdio>` and add a `using namespace std;` afterwards.  The C runtime library is part of the standard C++ library, and experience suggests it tends to be much faster than using iostreams, possibly because it doesn't bother with locales.

Comment: I really wanted to run this on my Mac for kicks, but alas no compiley. I do love how tight it is, though.

Comment: @WhozCraig: If you delete the top line and the two calls to `_setmode()`, it should work on any Unix system.  From a quick google it seems gcc uses its own locking for thread-safety too, which can be turned off by replacing `getchar()` with `getchar_unlocked()` and `putchar()` with `putchar_unlocked()`.

Comment: I'll have to lose <io.h> as well. (odd I know, but it isn't needed if the rest are gone by the looks of it). Fwiw, i don't use gcc; Apple LLVM instead, but I can set the mode for compatibility, so it should work ok. thanks.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Cool, if you manage to get it working I'd be interested to hear how fast or slow it is!